# Why will a T value be lower for between subject design then within subject design?

Tags: self-study, mathematical-statistics, t-test, repeated-measures, psychology

You have run a within-subject experiment. You conduct a t-test and find a t-statistic of 3.5 Because you have no life, you also conduct a t-test suitable for a between-subject design on the data and find that the t-statistic is 2.8.

Can you explain why the t-value was lower for the latter test?

Can you think of a case in which there would be no difference between the two tests?

Doing the opposite (computing a t-test suitable for a within-subject design on a between-subject study) will not always be possible. Why?

Comment: This looks like it was copied directly from a textbook or homework problem. If so, you may want to add the`self-study` tag. Thanks!

Comment: thanks for letting me know!